# Properties вида item1, item2 ... itemN

Tags: java, configuration, properties

Существует ли стандартное средство  в java (или в библиотеках) для чтения properties вида:

```
Item0 : string0
Item1 : string1
...
ItemN : stringN
```

?

Comment: а в чем сложность реализовтаь самостоятельно? на каждую строку делаете split(" : ") и в получившемся массиве нулевой элемент - имя параметра, первый - значение

Comment: Вопрос именно про элегантное и стандартное решение. В Apache Commons Configuration есть средство обработки properties вида: _item = string1, string2, string3_. `String[] items = config.getStringArray("item");` Но у меня чуть более специфическая ситуация.

Answer (score 1):

Вы смотрели java.util.Properties ?

Будет как-то так. Дальше перебор

```
fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
property.load(fis);
String item0 = property.getProperty("Item0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Стандартные средства хорошо определяют разделители. проблем не вижу

```
    String s = "Item0 : string0\n"
               + "Item1 : string1\n"
               + "ItemN : stringN";

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new StringReader(s));
    p.list(System.out);
```

вывод

```
-- listing properties --
ItemN=stringN
Item1=string1
Item0=string0
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/wqDA5h)

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Берите [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/).

В нем можно реализовать кастомный читатель `.properties`, где разделителем будет не `=`, [как предусмотрено стандартом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties), а любой другой символ, типа:

```
public class MyPropertiesReader extends PropertiesConfiguration.PropertiesReader {
    public MyPropertiesReader(Reader in) {
        super(in, ':');
    }
    //blah-blah
}
```

[Руководство здесь](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Properties_files)

Comment: В стандарте указано несколько разделителей и с ними со всеми Apache Commons Configuration работает без лишних усилий. Мой вопрос именно про поля: item0, item1... itemN

Comment: @DmitryRoo значит мы вас неверно поняли - можно в студию просто пример ваших пропертис, а не шаблон `item0, item1...`